# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null Javascripting

Tags: javascript, dynamic, row

```
var i = 0;
function addLine() {
        i++;        
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML += '<input type="text" name="description['+i+']" id="description['+i+']"/>';
        div.innerHTML += '<input type="text" name="quantity['+i+']" id="quantity['+i+']" onkeyup="sum();"/>';
        div.innerHTML += '<input type="text" name="price['+i+']" id="price['+i+']" onkeyup="sum();"/>';
        div.innerHTML += '<input type="text" name="lineTotal['+i+']" id="lineTotal['+i+']" readonly/>';
        div.innerHTML += '<input type="button" onclick="removeLine(this)" value="-">';
        div.innerHTML += '<input type="button" onclick="addLine();" value="+" />';

        document.getElementById('items').appendChild(div);
    }

    function removeLine(div) {
      document.getElementById('items').removeChild(div.parentNode);
    }

    function sum() {
        var q = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
        var p = document.getElementById('price').value;
        var result = parseInt(q) * parseInt(p);

        if(q=="" || p==""){
            document.getElementById('lineTotal').value = 0;
        }

        if (!isNaN(result)) {
            document.getElementById('lineTotal').value = result;
        } 
    }


</script>
```

Below is the html

```
<tr>

    <td><input type="text" name="description[]"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity[]" onkeyup="sum();"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="price[]" id="price[]" onkeyup="sum();"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lineTotal[]" id="lineTotal[]" readonly /></td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="addLine();" value="+" /></td>

</tr>
```

So when i try to add a new line it works very well with no problems.

When I do the calculation for the first  in the html it does all the calculations without any problems, but when i add the new dynamic line, i cannot calculate. Been trying to solve this for days, still haven't got a result so i decided to ask here.

Your help will be very well appreciated.

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID should be unique

Also I replaced DIV with TR and added TD to be consistent with table you have

```
<table id="items">
<tr>

    <td><input type="text" name="description[]"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity[0]" onkeyup="sum(0);"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="price[]" id="price[0]" onkeyup="sum(0);"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lineTotal[]" id="lineTotal[0]" readonly /></td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="addLine();" value="+" /></td>

</tr>
</table>
<script>
var i = 0;
function addLine() {
        i++;        
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="description['+i+']" id="description['+i+']"/>';
        row.appendChild(td);
        td = document.createElement('td');
        td.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="quantity['+i+']" id="quantity['+i+']" onkeyup="sum('+i+');"/>';
        row.appendChild(td);
        td = document.createElement('td');
        td.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="price['+i+']" id="price['+i+']" onkeyup="sum('+i+');"/>';
        row.appendChild(td);
        td = document.createElement('td');
        td.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="lineTotal['+i+']" id="lineTotal['+i+']" readonly/>';
        row.appendChild(td);
        td = document.createElement('td');
        td.innerHTML = '<input type="button" onclick="removeLine(this.parentNode.parentNode)" value="-">';
        row.appendChild(td);
        td = document.createElement('td');
        td.innerHTML = '<input type="button" onclick="addLine();" value="+" />';
        row.appendChild(td);

        document.getElementById('items').appendChild(row);
    }

    function removeLine(row) {
      document.getElementById('items').removeChild(row);
    }

    function sum(i) {
        var q = document.getElementById('quantity['+i+']').value;
        var p = document.getElementById('price['+i+']').value;
        var result = parseInt(q) * parseInt(p);

        if(q=="" || p==""){
            document.getElementById('lineTotal['+i+']').value = 0;
        }

        if (!isNaN(result)) {
            document.getElementById('lineTotal['+i+']').value = result;
        } 
    }

</script>
```

Comment: I updated a bit, to make it work with real table with TRs and TDs

Comment: done :).. If i want to calculate all the lineTotal into a subtoal output. how do i do it? Sorry but i am really new to javscripting and I'm finding it difficult to go about it.

Comment: Use for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {}

Comment: function subTotal(i){
   
   var total = 0; 
   var sub = document.getElementById('lineTotal['+i+']');
   
   for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
   var amount = sub[ j ].innerHTML.match( /[0-9]+.[0-9]+/ );
   total += Number( amount );
   } 
   document.getElementById('subtotal').value = total.toFixed(2);
 }

Comment: thats my code with an onclick on the subtotal field but doesnt work and just displays 0.00 on the field :(

Comment: Here is a solution for your problem http://jsfiddle.net/w67s9w8v/ please note I added button and method to calculate subTotal but I call this method in sum so it's automatically calculate subtotal on change inputs